# How to generate a random frozen lake map in OpenAI?

Tags: openai-gym

They recently added the capability of generating a random frozen map. But there is no accompanying documentation of how to use it. I want to use it in an ongoing project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the function generate_random_map() from the frozen_lake module and use the map returned by the function as an argument to the desc parameter when creating the environment:

```
import gym
from gym.envs.toy_text.frozen_lake import generate_random_map

random_map = generate_random_map(size=20, p=0.8)

env = gym.make("FrozenLake-v0", desc=random_map)
env.reset()
env.render()
```

the generate_random_map() function takes two parameters:

- size: is the size of the sides of the grid
- p: is the probability of a frozen tile.

Another option is to create a subclass of the FrozenLake environment that takes the size and p parameters directly and register it as a new environment. You can find an example of this approach on the following repository:

https://github.com/rodmsmendes/gym-toy-text-ext

Comment: Also, I wrote a blog post about it:
https://reinforcementlearning4.fun/2019/06/24/create-frozen-lake-random-maps/